# php - Simple HTML Dom: How to nest foreach loop to correctly echo output

Tags: php, foreach, simple-html-dom

Sorry if the title is slightly confusing, I couldn't find the correct words to formulate it correctly.

A little bit of context: I'm trying to get data from 2 classes and echo them into 1 line.

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($site->find('.version a') as $source) {
foreach ($site->find('.version_numb') as $pwGetFrame) {
$pwFrame = $pwGetFrame->innertext;

$getURL = $source->href;

$pwVersion = $source->plaintext;

echo '<div class="linkFrame"><a href="'.$getURL.'">'.$pwVersion.'</a><div>'.$pwFrame.'</p></div>';
   }
}
```

This code made each `linkframe` be inside the previous `linkframe` making it somewhat like inception.

What can I do to make this work correctly?

Comment: What are your trying to achieve? Are you sure you need to use nested foreach loops?

Comment: @Dan Yes, I tried using just one foreach however it didn't work. It showed all the results for the class inside the foreach but only showed 1 result for the class that wasn't inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not very clear to understand what you're after from your question, I believe you're looking for something like the following:

```
$source = $site->find('.version a');
$pwGetFrame = $site->find('.version_numb');

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($source); $i++) {
    $pwFrame = $pwGetFrame[$i]->innertext;
    $getURL = $source[$i]->href;
    $pwVersion = $source[$i]->plaintext;
    echo '<div class="linkFrame"><a href="'.$getURL.'">'.$pwVersion.'</a><div>'.$pwFrame.'</p></div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly. I didn't know sizeof() was a thing. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Simon You're welcome. :) You should also fix the issues with your markup that Brian pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that there are two open `<div>` tags and no open `<p>` tags in that snippet?

Maybe you are looking for

```
echo '<div class="linkFrame"><a href="'.$getURL.'">'.$pwVersion.'</a><p>'.$pwFrame.'</p></div>';
```